# How to throw a custom fault on a JAX-WS web service?

Tags: java, web-services, exception, jax-ws, soapfault

How do you throw a custom soap fault on a JAX-WS web service? How can I specify the `faultCode`, `faultString` and `detail` of the soap fault? Is it possible to set the value of the `detail` as bean instead of a `String`?

Please note that I'm developing using code-first approach.

Comment: See the following thread: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358204/jax-ws-soap-faults-not-appearing-in-wsdl][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15358204/jax-ws-soap-faults-not-appearing-in-wsdl

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Use the `@WebFault` annotation.

You can see a good example in [Using SOAP Faults and Exceptions in Java JAX-WS Web Services - Eben Hewitt on Java](http://io.typepad.com/eben_hewitt_on_java/2009/07/using-soap-faults-and-exceptions-in-java-jaxws-web-services.html).

You will see the example:

```
@WebFault(name="CheckVerifyFault",
    targetNamespace="http://www.example.com")
public class CheckVerifyFault extends Exception {

    /**
     * Java type that goes as soapenv:Fault detail element.
     */
    private CheckFaultBean faultInfo;

    public CheckVerifyFault(String message, CheckFaultBean faultInfo) {
        super(message);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public CheckVerifyFault(String message, CheckFaultBean faultInfo, 
           Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
        this.faultInfo = faultInfo;
    }

    public CheckFaultBean getFaultInfo() {
        return faultInfo;
    }
}
```

---

**UPDATE**

Another way is to declare the ***typical* exception** in the `throws` clause.

e.g. Suppose the following is my exception class:

```
package pkg.ex;

public class FooException extends Exception {

    public FooException(String message, Throwable cause) {
        super(message, cause);
    }

}
```

And the next class is the service implementation.

```
package pkg.ws;

import javax.jws.WebService;
import pkg.ex.FooException;

@WebService(serviceName = "FooSvc")
public class FooService {

    public String sayHello(String name) throws FooException {
        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            Throwable t = new IllegalArgumentException("Empty name");
            throw new FooException("There is one error", t);
        }
        return "Hello, " + name;
    }

}
```

If my request is:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:ws="http://ws.pkg/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:sayHello>
         <arg0>Peter</arg0>
      </ws:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

There is no problem:

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <ns2:sayHelloResponse xmlns:ns2="http://ws.pkg/">
         <return>Hello, Peter</return>
      </ns2:sayHelloResponse>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

But...

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
                  xmlns:ws="http://ws.pkg/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <ws:sayHello>
         <arg0></arg0>
      </ws:sayHello>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

Then...

```
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
   <S:Body>
      <S:Fault xmlns:ns4="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope">
         <faultcode>S:Server</faultcode>
         <faultstring>There is one error</faultstring>
         <detail>
            <ns2:FooException xmlns:ns2="http://ws.pkg/">
               <message>There is one error</message>
            </ns2:FooException>
         </detail>
      </S:Fault>
   </S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the link! Got it working. Is there a way so that I can also specify my faultCode? How can I return a custom faultCode using the code above?

Comment: @Arci, I have the same problem and it is impossible unless you construct a SoapFaultException yourself. Real crap!

Comment: With `@WebFault` I always get _Marshalling Error: class my.test.MyServiceFault nor any of its super class is known to this context_. Ended up throwing `SOAPFaultException` as presented in the other answer.

Answer (score 9):

```
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFactory;
import javax.xml.soap.SOAPFault;
import javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException;
import javax.xml.namespace.QName;
...

SOAPFactory soapFactory = SOAPFactory.newInstance();
SOAPFault soapFault = soapFactory.createFault(
        "Your custom message", 
         new QName("http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/", "Client")); 
throw new SOAPFaultException(soapFault);
```

To choose the right fault code, see http://www.tutorialspoint.com/soap/soap_fault.htm .