# web services catching custom java exception in c# client

Tags: c#, java, service, web, faultexception

I have a custom java exception called ClientAlreadyExistsException this exception is thrown by a signup method in java and I use Apache CXF to generate the web services.
Now in my C# client when I call for the signup method I can't catch the exception as it always returns an error FaultException`1 but in which I can actually see the text i wrote in the java exception.

I tried catching a SoapException but it didn't work and I even tried this :

```
try
        {
            //signup method call

        }
        catch (FaultException<ClientAlreadyExistsException> ex)
        {
            //code
        }
```

Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your C# client, executes a request to a SOAP web service. It has no difference if the SOAP server is implemented using Java or something else. The only way to indicate a specific error to your client, is to integrate the custom error in the SOAP mechanism. You could use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13596260/how-to-throw-a-custom-fault-on-a-jax-ws-web-service), or [this](http://willemjiang.blogspot.gr/2011/01/how-to-map-soap-fault-message-with.html) as a reference.

Hope I helped!